# C++ typedef member function signature syntax

Tags: c++, typedef, member-functions, method-signature

I want to declare type definition for a member function signature. Global function typedefs look like this:

```
typedef int (function_signature)(int, int);
typedef int (*function_pointer) (int, int);
```

But I'm not able to the same thing for a member function:

```
typedef int (foo::memberf_signature)(int, int);   // memberf_pointer is not a member of foo
typedef int (foo::*memberf_pointer)(int, int);
```

It sounds logically to me, because `foo::` is the syntax to access a member in the class `foo`.

How can I typedef just the signature?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'm confused, is the last `typedef` not what you want?

Comment: That seems inhomogeneous to me. It's possible to typedef a function declared at global-scope, but it isn't possible to typedef a method. And yes, I'm differentiating between a signature and a function pointer type.

Comment: yeah C++ syntax should allow int (foo::&memberf_reference)(int, int )

Comment: @GManNickG 10 years late, I know (there might be other late readers, though…) – but I see clearly the intention: `typedef int (function_signature)(int, int);` allows to write later on `function_signature* thePointer` – not hiding the pointer nature of the variable as the pointer typedef would do, and apparently the same should be done for member function pointers ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For questions regarding the awkward function pointer syntax, I personally use a cheat-sheet: [The Function Pointers Tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20170606042951/http://www.oopweb.com/CPP/Documents/FunctionPointers/Volume/CCPP/FPT/em_fpt.html) ([downloadable here](http://www.newty.de/fpt/dload.html), thanks to [Vector](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712579/vector) for pointing it out).

The signature of a member function, however, is a bit different from the signature of a regular function, as you experienced.

As you probably know, a member function has a hidden parameter, `this`, whose type need be specified.

```
// C++11 and above.
using Member = int (Foo::*)(int, int);

// C++03 and below.
typedef int (Foo::*Member)(int, int);
```

does let you specify that the first element passed to the function will be a `Foo*` (and thus your method really takes 3 arguments, when you think of it, not just 2.

However there is another reason too, for forcing you to specify the type.

A function pointer might refer to a virtual function, in which case things can get quite complicated. Therefore, the very *size* of the in-memory representation changes depending on the type of function. Indeed, on Visual Studio, a function pointer's size might vary between 1 and 4 times the size of a regular pointer. This depends on whether the function is virtual, notably.

Therefore, the class the function refers to **is part of the signature**, and there is no work-around.

Comment: @BЈовић: and it was such a good link too... oh well thankfully I knew a second article ;)

Comment: New working link with _downloads_ for [**The Function Pointers Tutorial**](http://www.newty.de/fpt/dload.html)

Comment: How would this look with C++11 "using" syntax?

Comment: @paulm: Good question, post edited. It's basically the same, except the name is extracted, and thus easier to find.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Is this valid? Are you sure that the type of a non-static member function/data (not the type of a member pointer to that function/data) is `Return(Class::*)(Args...)` and not `Return(Class::)(Args...)`? If so, then is it true that `this*` is the reason for the `*` in the member's or member pointer's identical type (iow the fact that `this*` is a **"pointer"** that's always part of the signature)?

Comment: @Nikos: You can try the syntax yourself in a compiler: `Return(Class::)(Args...)` is not valid syntax. `this` (not `this*`) is always a pointer, despite never being null, and is passed as a pointer to methods. The invocation syntax is `(this->*method)(args...)` or `(ref.*method)(args...)`, which is another layer of weird...

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? In the next 3 examples `A`, `B` and `C` compile but not `D`.
`template <typename T, typename... A> using A = int (T::*)(A...);
template <typename T, typename... A> using B = void (T::*)(A...);
template <typename T> using C = int T::*;
template <typename T> using D = void T::*;
`

Comment: @PatrickFromberg: C and D are NOT function pointers (and thus outside this question), they are pointers to data-members. Different syntax, and a data-member cannot have for type `void` thus D is wrong.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Yes, this is why I was surprised to see pointer to member used as parameter type for functions here: `template< class M, class T>  mem_fn(M T::* pm) noexcept`. I was trying to figure out how `std::invoke` works exactly and it works for void returning functions. I should create a dedicated question actually.

Comment: Late, I know, but actually I don't think this post answers the question; as far as I see, intention is not dropping the class name, but just dropping the asterisk to get the signature itself, not a pointer, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/xnaj6oTvn). Answer: Impossible, not foreseen by the standard… (Though still nicely explained why the class specification cannot be dropped!)

Comment: @Aconcagua: Indeed, it looks I was slightly off.

Answer (score 8):

You can factor out the target class in modern C++ (post 11) by utilizing the **'typedefing' qualities** of **template aliases**. What you need would look like like:

```
template<typename T>
using memberf_pointer = int (T::*)(int, int);
```

Yet at the point of declaration, a pointer to member function utilizing this syntax would need to specify the target class:

```
// D is a member function taking (int, int) and returning int
memberf_pointer<foo> mp = &foo::D;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work with your current syntax is that operator precedence dictates that you're referring to a function named `foo::memberf_signature`, not any sort of type.

I don't know for sure if you can do this or not, but I couldn't come up with any combination of parenthese that induced the code to compile with g++ 4.2.

Comment: What about just `::memberf_signature` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
#include <iostream>

class foo
  {
public:
  int g (int x, int y) { return x + y ; }
  } ;

typedef int (foo::*memberf_pointer)(int, int);

int main()
  {
  foo f ;
  memberf_pointer mp = &foo::g ;
  std::cout << (f.*mp) (5, 8) << std::endl ;
  }
```

Comment: That's a typedef for a member function pointer. That work's for me too, but isn't what I'm after ;)

Comment: OK, now I see what you want. But how do you plan to use this typedef, if you manage to create it?

Answer (score -3):

Well basically it can't work (at least I know no way using g++);
Using borland c++ compiler there would be the __closure keyword.

The reason why it does not compile is, that sizeof the functionpointer (on a x86 machine) occupies always <<32bits>>; but if you want to point to a class (interface) signature, the sizeof has to be 64bit: 32 bit for the this pointer (as the class interface is in the memory only once) and 32 bit for the actual function

But the __closure keyword is a bcb language 'hack' not standardized...

Comment: The fact that member function pointers and function pointers are of different sizes looks irrelevant to me.  Typically, `short` and `double` are of different sizes, but you can `typedef` with both of them.

Comment: The `this` pointer is normally passed as a first, hidden parameter. I haven't heard of any compiler using a 64-bit pointer to munge the this pointer into the pointer to an object.

Comment: That's absolutely wrong. The this pointer is stored in the (e.g. MSC) ECX-Register on IA-32 target machine. Any pointer is always 32-bit on such a system.